# Importing An Excel File From An Embedded File In A View

Tags: excel, import, lotusscript

I'm currently attempting to take an embedded file (an excel xlsx file in this case) from a document inside a view and import the data into a DataArray for editing. The way the system I am working on is set-up, I will not a local drive to ExtractFile() onto - so I was curious if there is a way to basically take the xlsx file directly from the document that has it embedded in it and 'open' it in my agent to then extract the data from.

Thanks!

-Mike

Comment: Is it actually embedded (as an OLE object), or is it really attached?

Comment: Hi, is your agent intended to run on the server or the client?

Comment: Hi guys - thanks for the response. It's intended to run on the server. Also, it is literally attached to the document.